# Предложение в роли сказуемого или нет?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Купил айфон. Основной минус - не могу привыкнуть к другому управлению.

**Основной минус** - подлежащее, **не могу привыкнуть к другому управлению** - предложение в роли сказуемого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Основной минус — не могу привыкнуть к другому управлению.***

По структуре мы действительно видим, что в позиции сказуемого в простом предложении находится другое простое предложение. Сравнить: *Основной минус — сложное привыкание к другому управлению.*

Но такие предложения **классифицируются по общей системе,** поэтому ближе всего оно к бессоюзному  сложному предложению (БСП).

Отношения между простыми предложениями **пояснительные**:  основной минус — какой. Первая часть в БСП — **номинативное** предложение.

**Примечание**

Номинативные структуры могут входит в БСП, например у Розенталя:

Кривые улицы, маленькие деревянные дома — такой была значительная часть Москвы в начале XX века. На стене ни одного образа — дурной знак.

Answer (score 2):

Это предложение можно рассматривать как *неполное сложноподчинённое*, в котором неполными являются и главное, и придаточное предложения. В главном предложении опущено сказуемое, а в придаточном - подлежащее и союзное слово - их замещает тире (могло быть и двоеточие); исходный полный вариант мог быть таким:

> Основной минус (**состоит** в том, что **я**) не могу привыкнуть к
>   другому управлению.

Отсюда видно, что подлежащих и сказуемых - по два ("минус" и "я"; "состоит" и "могу"); в неполном предложении опущенное подразумевается (причём "я" - безальтернативно).